# Home Brew PHP 7.2.5 Install with cURL

Tags: php, macos, curl, homebrew

I have a localhost development environment on my Mac that uses homebrew's `php` formula and I'm pulling my hair out trying to install with a custom path to cURL rather than the default Mac OS version (v7.54.0) that uses SecureTransport for SSL. SecureTransport causes a lot of issues with SSL requests to remote services, so OpenSSL is pretty much a requirement for my purposes.

Here's the process I've taken so far:

1. Installed curl through home brew with OpenSSL: `brew install curl --with-openssl`
2. Edited brew's `php` formula to modify the compile process, telling `./configure` to use the brew installed curl (v7.59.0). I've tried `--with-curl=/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.59.0` and also `--with-curl=#{Formula["curl"].opt_prefix}`. The second option is just a dynamic symlink to the former.
3. Save the edits and rebuild php from the source: `brew reinstall --build-from-source php`

To verify that I have the write `./configure` options I added a temporary line to my Brew formula edits that spits out the `args` passed. Here's what this looks like:

```
--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.2.5
--localstatedir=/usr/local/var
--sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc/php/7.2
--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php/7.2
--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d
--with-pear=/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.2.5/share/php/pear
--enable-bcmath
--enable-calendar
--enable-dba
--enable-dtrace
--enable-exif
--enable-ftp
--enable-fpm
--enable-intl
--enable-mbregex
--enable-mbstring
--enable-mysqlnd
--enable-opcache-file
--enable-pcntl
--enable-phpdbg
--enable-phpdbg-webhelper
--enable-shmop
--enable-soap
--enable-sockets
--enable-sysvmsg
--enable-sysvsem
--enable-sysvshm
--enable-wddx
--enable-zip
--with-apxs2=/usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/apxs
--with-bz2
--with-curl=/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.59.0
--with-fpm-user=_www
--with-fpm-group=_www
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/opt/freetype
--with-gd
--with-gettext=/usr/local/opt/gettext
--with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp
--with-icu-dir=/usr/local/opt/icu4c
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/opt/jpeg
--with-kerberos
--with-layout=GNU
--with-ldap
--with-ldap-sasl
--with-libedit
--with-libzip
--with-mhash
--with-mysql-sock=/tmp/mysql.sock
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd
--with-ndbm
--with-openssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl
--with-password-argon2=/usr/local/opt/argon2
--with-pdo-dblib=/usr/local/opt/freetds
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd
--with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr/local/opt/unixodbc
--with-pdo-pgsql=/usr/local/opt/libpq
--with-pgsql=/usr/local/opt/libpq
--with-pic
--with-png-dir=/usr/local/opt/libpng
--with-pspell=/usr/local/opt/aspell
--with-sodium=/usr/local/opt/libsodium
--with-unixODBC=/usr/local/opt/unixodbc
--with-webp-dir=/usr/local/opt/webp
--with-xmlrpc
--with-xsl
--with-zlib
```

By all intensive purposes this *should* be working, but when I open up a `phpinfo()` after reinstalling php from the source I'm seeing the following under the **Configure Command** value:

```
'./configure' 
'--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.2.5' 
'--localstatedir=/usr/local/var' 
'--sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc/php/7.2' 
'--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php/7.2' 
'--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d' 
'--with-pear=/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.2.5/share/php/pear' 
'--enable-bcmath' 
'--enable-calendar' 
'--enable-dba' 
'--enable-dtrace' 
'--enable-exif' 
'--enable-ftp' 
'--enable-fpm' 
'--enable-intl' 
'--enable-mbregex' 
'--enable-mbstring' 
'--enable-mysqlnd' 
'--enable-opcache-file' 
'--enable-pcntl' 
'--enable-phpdbg' 
'--enable-phpdbg-webhelper' 
'--enable-shmop' 
'--enable-soap' 
'--enable-sockets' 
'--enable-sysvmsg' 
'--enable-sysvsem' 
'--enable-sysvshm' 
'--enable-wddx' 
'--enable-zip' 
'--with-apxs2=/usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/apxs' 
'--with-bz2' 
'--with-fpm-user=_www' 
'--with-fpm-group=_www' 
'--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/opt/freetype' 
'--with-gd' 
'--with-gettext=/usr/local/opt/gettext' 
'--with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp' 
'--with-icu-dir=/usr/local/opt/icu4c' 
'--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/opt/jpeg' 
'--with-kerberos' 
'--with-layout=GNU' 
'--with-ldap' 
'--with-ldap-sasl' 
'--with-libedit' 
'--with-libzip' 
'--with-mhash' 
'--with-mysql-sock=/tmp/mysql.sock' 
'--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' 
'--with-ndbm' 
'--with-openssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl' 
'--with-password-argon2=/usr/local/opt/argon2' 
'--with-pdo-dblib=/usr/local/opt/freetds' 
'--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' 
'--with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr/local/opt/unixodbc' 
'--with-pdo-pgsql=/usr/local/opt/libpq' 
'--with-pgsql=/usr/local/opt/libpq' 
'--with-pic' 
'--with-png-dir=/usr/local/opt/libpng' 
'--with-pspell=/usr/local/opt/aspell' 
'--with-sodium=/usr/local/opt/libsodium' 
'--with-unixODBC=/usr/local/opt/unixodbc' 
'--with-webp-dir=/usr/local/opt/webp' 
'--with-xmlrpc' 
'--with-xsl' 
'--with-zlib' 
'--with-curl'
```

If you notice, there's a trailing `--with-curl` at the tail of this, while everything else is in the order that's defined in the brew formula. I have no idea where or how this is appended onto the `./configure` command, but this may be related to the cause of the issue.

For reference, here's the exact content of the modified `php.rb` formula for Brew:

https://gist.github.com/Kevinlearynet/a44ffa2107a1b6e09935766a9e46cfd4

Either way, I'm completely stumped here. Any help or assistance is very much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure it suits your needs but have you tried to install php `—with-homebrew-curl`?

Comment: With `brew install php` being part of homebrew-core now, that command was actually removed and is the main cause of this issue here. Previously when I had `brew install php72` installed that was the approach I took, but sadly it's not possible anymore.

Comment: One other note that's related here, the edits I make with `brew edit php` were actually based on what the `--with-homebrew-curl` changed inside of the formula based on this: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/blob/d9944161c70e793df85cce747d95aa804c95a1b7/Abstract/abstract-php.rb

Comment: In linux, the issue is identical. Each 7 version has his own folder. You should ba able to search trough all available with wildcards: `apt list php7*` or similar for brew.

Comment: @Cryptopat That doesn't provide anything of value related to the issue I've outlined. I can run `brew list | grep php` to do this, but then I get exactly what I expect and want to see. How that version of PHP is compiled is the issue.

Comment: I came up with a solution that works for me (see my answer below).  Let me know if it doesn't work for you ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've applied the patch supplied by dossy and it works!

Below are the specific steps to take to solve the issue. More details on what this fixes can be found below.

1. `cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core`
2. `curl -s https://github.com/dossy/homebrew-core/commit/b75fe286f79e2b89548c5ed1bbe1958313c5c103.patch | patch -p1`
3. `brew reinstall php --build-from-source`

The specific source of issue appears to be that the `libxml2` library is needed to replace Mac's built-in `libcurl`, which is what ultimately forces PHP's dependency on **SecureTransport**. These two lines in php.rb were the critical part of the fix for my purposes:

- depends_on "libxml2"
- --with-libxml-dir=#{Formula["libxml2"].opt_prefix}

For my specific circumstance I had to reset my editted home brew formula (php.rb) to the source because I had previously editted it. As a result applying the patch didn't work at first. If you've also editted your php.rb formula then I'd reset it to the source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/master/Formula/php.rb.

In the linked article on medium.com dossy suggests the follow command to build after applying to patch, `brew install php --build-from-source`. If you already have PHP installed you'll need to use **reinstall** in place of **install** instead.